# MEF, WPF, and Mocking

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism, mef, structuremap

I am about to start a new WPF project with PRISM 4.1 (and Reactive UI). Now, I am bit unsure about the IOC/DI bit. I've played around with MEF and Structure Map and so far I really like MEF and its extensibility feature.

The problem is so far I've always use Structure Map as my IOC/DI and to help me with unit test (I use MOQ for mocking).

Is it recommended to use MEF as DI/IOC? Or should I stick with Structure Map for my IOC/DI, and just use MEF in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your needs for the IOC, but it is possible to use MEF as your IOC.

Glenn Block has a blog post about this from 2009.

http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2009/08/16/should-i-use-mef-for-my-general-ioc-needs/

Mark Seeman has a chapter on MEF as IOC in his book.

[http://www.amazon.com/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1332021360&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501)

Comment: I know that it is possible to use MEF as IOC/DI - but not sure if it's "recommended". Basically I am trying to get a feeling if people are starting to use MEF as IOC/DI? If not, any reason why not? Since I am almost certainly will use MEF in WPF, I thought it would be nice not to have 2 different libraries, but just not sure. My IOC/DI needs are pretty basic, POCO Object Factory and mocking mainly.

Comment: Reading your first link, even Glenn Block does not seem to recommend MEF as IOC, but things may change with MEF2 since it will come with fluent interface (attribute-less). Still, I am interested to know if anyone has any success with using MEF as their IOC/DI.